# Unknown column in field list error

Tags: mysql, join

I am doing an inner join on a bunch of tables and I surely made that all of those tables exist. But when everytime I input my query, it always says '

> Unknown column 'tbl_undertime.ut_date' in 'field list'

I am very sure that `tbl_undertime` is a table under my database but I don't know why it keeps on returning such error. I've already dropped the table and made a new table again with the same name and column but still gives me the same error.

A help would be very much appreciated.

```
select tbl_employee.lname, tbl_employee.fname, tbl_employee.mi,     
tbl_employee.sss_no,
tbl_employee.philhealth_no, tbl_employee.dept_id, tbl_employee.salaryperday,
tbl_earlyout.timeout_date, tbl_late.late_date, tbl_overtime.ot_date,    
tbl_absent.absentdate,
tbl_leave.leave_type, tbl_leave.start_date, tbl_leave.end_date,   
tbl_undertime.utdate, tbl_cashadv.cashadv_date,
tbl_pay15.gross_sal
from tbl_employee
inner join tbl_earlyout
on tbl_employee.empid = tbl_earlyout.empid
inner join tbl_late
on tbl_late.empid = tbl_overtime.empid
inner join tbl_overtime
on tbl_overtime.empid = tbl_absent.empid
inner join tbl_absent
on tbl_absent.empid = tbl_leave.empid
inner join tbl_leave
on tbl_leave.empid = tbl_undertime.empid
inner join tbl_cashadv
on tbl_cashadv.empid = tbl_pay15.empid;

+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ut_id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| empid         | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| utdate        | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ut_mins_hours | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Fancy responding to the answer as not heard from you since you posted?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it would appear your table column is `utdate` not `ut_date`. I would imagine a typo is your issue, hence `Unknown column 'tbl_undertime.ut_date`.